# Question about an Interesting effect regarding light and colors in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, color

I have noticed an interesting effect in cycle.

A scene containing one glass cube and a point light inside it.

When the **point light is white** and I change the color of the glass cube, this happens:

[image]

Nothing out of the ordinary, I suppose.

However, when I change the **point light color to red** and then change the glass cube color, this happens:

[image]

When the color goes through blue shades, the point light disappears!

Does anybody know why is this happening?

And is it a render limitation, or does this happen in the real world too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because it's accurate.

If you have a colored translucent material, that means it's filtering different colors to result in the final color. If a translucent material is blue that means it's filtering out green and red, resulting in only the blue light passing through. White light is a mix of all the colors in the visible spectrum, so it has all the colors contained in it. So no matter what colors you filter out, the light will still be visible (only tinted). When your light is red and the translucent material is blue, it will filter out the light completely, because the red light doesn't contain any blue light to pass through.

Comment: I'll add to it, that to my understanding Blender rendering is not spectrum based, after all you only set colors using RGB components. This means that while normally there are metamers and a perception of color is just a result of contrast between the data from types of cones and the light spectrum typically has some tail leaking to other hues, in Blender the light consists of just 3 wavelengths with a super sharp cutoff in the spectrum, so a perfectly blue material cannot possibly bounce perfectly red light.

Comment: thank you both for answering my question